# MongoDB : find documents having 2 values in Array conforming to multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose, we have documents:

```
{_id : 1, arr : [5,50]}
{_id : 2, arr : [11,53]}
```

The goal is to find documents which have 2 values in array, one has to be in range(4,9), the second in range(45,55).
In this case, only document with _id : 1 should return.

Tried this:
`db.Collection.find({arr : {$elemMatch : {$gte : 4, $lte : 9}}})` - returns the first document
`db.Collection.find({arr : {$elemMatch : {$gte : 45, $lte : 55}}})` - returns both

How to combine these criteria together?

```
db.Collection.find({arr : {$and : [{$elemMatch : {$gte : 4, $lte : 9}}, {$elemMatch : {$gte : 45, $lte : 55}}]}})
```

returns : **error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $and", "code" : 10068 }**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but the `$and` needs to be at the top level of your conditions object:

```js
db.Collection.find({$and: [
    {arr: {$elemMatch: {$gte: 4, $lte: 9}}},
    {arr: {$elemMatch: {$gte: 45, $lte: 55}}}
]})
```

If you also want to ensure that these are the *only* two elements, then you can add another term to the `$and` array to check that:

```js
db.Collection.find({$and: [
    {arr: {$elemMatch: {$gte: 4, $lte: 9}}},
    {arr: {$elemMatch: {$gte: 45, $lte: 55}}},
    {'arr.2': {$exists: false}}
]})
```

Comment: To satisfy the first requirement "find documents which have 2 values in array" you may need to put the query `{arr : {$exists:true}, $where:'this.arr.length=2'}`

Comment: @chridam You don't need that because a single element can't satisfy both ranges.

Comment: What if there is an array with more than 2 elements? I am not sure if the OP meant any arbitrary two elements or not ...

Comment: @chridam Good point. I'm not sure either, but I updated my answer to include an option for that.